# Avoiding border radius with text in span

Tags: html, css, text, word-wrap

I have an editable span with rounded corners as shown in the picture below. As you can see, the text runs off the corner and I would love a way to keep the text inside the box. is there a good way to do this? I don't want to add padding that goes all the way down the sides or across the top, I really just want to avoid the corners with border-radii. [Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/klaytonme/9srqL4ma/7/) demonstrating the current state.

Thanks!
[image: Text overflowing the span's border]

Current CSS:

```
#container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    transition: border 0.2s;
    border: 2px solid rgba(128, 223, 255, 0);
    border-radius: 7px;
    display: table-row;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

.typeSpace {
  background-color: green;
    display: inline;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align:center;
  white-space: nowrap;
    left: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    
    overflow: auto;
    -ms-overflow-style: none;
    overflow-y: hidden;
  text-align: left;
}

#borderText {
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    font-size: 17px);
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: 15px);
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: Create a fiddle to get help better.

Comment: add some padding , that should help

Comment: I've added a JSFiddle and some explanation as to why I don't want to use padding. Let me know if there is a better way to use padding that I don't know about!

Comment: For the padding, besides box-sizing that can modify how it is applied, it is quiet simple and here is not much tricks around it. You may also take a look at text-indent . example with your fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/rdsx6174/ (floatting pseudo(or not) element could also do the trick https://jsfiddle.net/rdsx6174/1/ ) shape outside can also be an hint https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/vwqKyR

Answer (score 0):

So what you want this to look like, is something like this? `_` representing automatic "spacing".

```
_XX XXX X_
XXX XXX XX
X XXXX XXX
```

This could be done by inserting two elements into the span before the text, and then floating one to the left, and one to the right.

Only, your span is editable here (was that supposed to be `contenteditable`, or are you using some other mechanism? Either way, shouldn't matter) - so those would be likely to be removed by the user, when they modify the text content.

Okay, pseudo elements to the rescue! But wait, only `::before` would actually come before the text, `::after` would come behind it - and behind doesn't do us any good, when it comes to floating.

But we can use the `::before` pseudo element to generate the space on the right - and use `text-indent` for that on the left.

```css
#container {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  transition: border 0.2s;
  border: 2px solid rgba(128, 223, 255, 0);
  border-radius: calc(var(--scale)*7px);
  display: table-row;
  height: 200px;
  width: 300px;
}

.typeSpace {
  background-color: green;
  display: inline;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  left: calc(var(--scale) * 10px);
  right: calc(var(--scale) * 10px);

  overflow: auto;
  -ms-overflow-style: none;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  text-align: left;
  text-indent: 1em; /* provides the spacing on the left */
}

#borderText {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  top: 0;
  font-size: calc(var(--scale) * 17px);
  white-space: normal;
  line-height: calc(var(--scale) * 15px);
  border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}

/* provides the spacing on the right */
.typeSpace::before {
  content: "";
  float: right;
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <span class="typeSpace" id="borderText" editable>I wish I could see the corners of this text right here</span>
</div>
```

Of course this will only work for the top corners - if you needed the same thing at the bottom, this method won't do.

Using CSS Shapes would probably be another way to do it - but this one here is easier, I think.